# Що означає слово "прудерія"?

Tags: значення-слів

Доброго дня!
От зустрів таке речення ["Причиною може бути **прудерія** - "ні за що не посадять", "моя хата з краю"](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/lib/1109344642.html). Однак, якщо ввести це слово у Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови, він не дасть ніяких результатів.
Отож, можливо хтось знає, що це слово означає і чи взагалі воно є українським? А також у якому значенні воно вживається у данному реченні?

Comment: Воно? https://www.google.com/search?q=прудерія

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прудерія - фальшива сором'язливість

Джерело [тут](https://explain_words_uk.academic.ru/5502/%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)

Comment: Ще джерела: [О. Скалозуб «Словник чужомовних слів, виразів і приповідок, що вживаються в українській мові» (1933)](//archive.org/details/skalozub1933) (с. 316), [Я. Дашкевич «Володимир Гнатюк: документи і матеріали (1871—1989)» (1989)](//books.google.com/books?id=AIDYAAAAMAAJ&q=прудерія) (с. 438), [«Словничок з творів Івана Франка» на сайті «Збруч»](//zbruc.eu/node/26111) (у самого Франка: [1](//books.google.com/books?id=5sS1AAAAMAAJ&q=прудерія), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=LlxgAAAAMAAJ)), [«Рідкісні українські слова»](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/RareWords/P3.html).

Comment: Цікаво, чого хтось мінус поставив? (Хіба що тому що джерело не дуже авторитетне: якийсь «Толковый украинский словарь. 2014», в якого невідомі ні укладачі, ні видавництво. Але ж інформація очевидна, підтверджується безліччю інших джерел.)

Comment: @Sasha , щиро кажучи, це джерело - це перше посилання в Google за запитом "прудерія". А на рахунок -1 і сам дивуюсь, хоча б якийсь коментар на рахунок цього злишили чи що...